# Image in drawer not display in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am going to use image instead of Icon in drawer menu, but image is not displayed.

```
const profileIcon = (style) => {
  style.width = 20;
  style.height = 20;
  return (
    <Image
      {...style}
      source={require('../assets/example.jpg')}
    />
  )
}


const drawerData = [
  {
    title: 'profile',
    icon: profileIcon
  },
  ...
];

<SafeAreaView>
  <Drawer data={drawerData} onSelect={onSelect} />
</SafeAreaView>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsTAm.png

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think rendering `Image` as an icon is not allowed.

Try this instead

```js
import { 
  Image, 
  SafeAreaView, 
  StyleSheet, 
  ScrollView, 
  Dimensions,
  Text,
} from 'react-native'; 
import { 
  Drawer, 
  Layout, 
  Text, 
  TopNavigation, 
  TopNavigationAction, 
  Icon 
} from '@ui-kitten/components'


const Profile = ({ uri }) => (<View><Text>Profile</Text> <Image uri={uri} /></View>)

const drawerData = [
  {
    title: 'Item 1' 
  }
];

<SafeAreaView>
  <Drawer data={drawerData} onSelect={onSelect} header={Profile} />
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: @DmytroL, what UI Library are you using?

Comment: `import { Image, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 
'react-native';`


`import { Drawer, Layout, Text, TopNavigation, TopNavigationAction, Icon } 
from '@ui-kitten/components';`